# How to set the Content-Length header and it work in Cassini?

Tags: asp.net, http, http-headers, cassini, http-head

I'm working on a slightly low-level ASP.Net project. One of the things I need to support is properly handling HEAD requests. For the uninitiated, a HEAD request is basically just HTTP headers with no content.

Part of this includes a correct content-length. (Even though ASP.Net thinks that the content-length is 0)

I use this code for setting it:

```
HttpRequest r; .... 
if(r.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Content-Length")){
    r.Headers["Content-Length"]=length.ToString();
}else{
    r.AddHeader("Content-Length",length.ToString());
}
```

This runs fine on mod_mono+Apache and on Mono's implementation of `xsp`, however, on Microsoft's Cassini dev server, this produces a PlatformNotSupportedException with the text `This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.`

Are there any known workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Does it work in IIS? If so, you could always setup an IIS app and point it to your working environment.

Comment: I agree with MK_Dev that you should use IIS. Cassini is simply a toy, which is never suitable for "low-level ASP.NET project".

Comment: @LexLi My problem is that this is a library for other developers to use, so I really don't want to force everyone who uses my library to use IIS for development... I think I'll just say HEAD requests don't work with Cassini and call it good.

Comment: After the introduction of IIS 7, Microsoft soon released IIS Express to replace Cassini. I think that's a nice move to avoid issues like this. So it is time to dump Cassini. Besides, based on HTTP RFC 2616 section 4.4 and 14.13, your attempt to provide correct Content-Length is useless, as a proper implemented HTTP client should automatically ignore it following section 4.4 rule 1. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Comment: @LexLi hmmm.. interesting. I haven't seen that portion of the spec. I may have to ask another question to have someone explain that to me a bit more